# Regarding JSON to CSV

Tags: json, csv

I am trying to read a JSON file and convert it to a `.csv` file and I got this error.

```
employee_parsed = json.loads('E:/Masters_Materials/Data_Science/Food/train.json')
emp_data = employee_parsed['train']

# open a file for writing
employ_data = open('E:/Masters_Materials/Data_Science/Food/train.csv', 'a')

# create the csv writer object
csvwriter = csv.writer(employ_data)

count = 0

for emp in emp_data:
    if count == 0:
        header = emp.keys()
        csvwriter.writerow(header)
        count += 1
    csvwriter.writerow(emp.values())

employ_data.close()
```

Comment: Are you using any specific node module? Can you show the sample json record?

Answer (score 0):

Json should be in homogeneous collection.just write it into http response after setting the response type csv

1. you need to create a header of json object key in comma separated manner.
2. then create row by getting respective key values in comma separated manner.